# Radix Sort for sorting 32 bit integers

Tags: radix-sort

I am trying to understand radix sort. I just posted the question here and learned how a 32-bit integer is broken into 4-bit chunks. How does it take 4 passes? For example:
2147507648 can be broken down into 128 0 93 192. 2147507672 yields 128 0 93 216. Wouldn't LSD radix sort compare 216 with 192, 93 with 93, 0 with 0, and 128 with 128? Comparing 216 with 128 itself would take 3 passes right?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are 8-bit chunks, not 4-bit chunks. And you can process `n` bits in one pass as long as you have `2^n` bins to put things in.

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant four 8-bit chunks. Thank you for the response!